# WalletConnect V2 doesnt end session in the wallet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js, decentralized-applications, wallet-connect

I am trying to create a disconnect function in my reaction-dapp, but that only ends the session in walletConnect and the dapp in the wallet does not disconnect, and when I want to connect to another account it does not leave because it is as if it were reconnected in the same account that connected at the beginning, I'm using wagmi's useDisconnect.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.